# Using two tkinter commands on one button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an error logger that saves user input with a button.
I wanted to be able to clear the text entry automatically in the window after it was logged. I did some reading into lambda and it seemed like it might work, but it doesn't actually delete the text after pressing the log button. The Success/Error message still pops up, so its still running log_error_callback. Below is my code.

```
import csv
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("C:/Users/Public/Documents/Intel/Strata/CfgFiles/Stationdata.ini")  #Locationdata for PD dataframe.

for key, value in config["StationData"].items():
    print(value)
    
    
config.read("C:/Users/Public/Documents/Intel/Strata/CfgFiles/Appinfo.ini")

for key, version in config["About"].items():
    print(version)

def log_error(category, error):
    with open("//datagrovera.ra.intel.com/DeviceLabUser/Shared/Device lab Error Logger/error_log.txt", 'a', newline='')as error_log:
        writer = csv.writer(error_log, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow([datetime.datetime.now(), error, category, value, version])
        

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('300x600')
    root.title(value)
    category_var = tk.StringVar(root)
    category_var.set('Strata')
    category_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root, category_var, 'Strata', 'Prober', 'General')
    category_dropdown.pack(pady=10)

    error_label = tk.Label(root, text='Error:')
    error_label.pack()
    v=tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical')
    v.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    error_entry = tk.Text(root, yscrollcommand=v.set)
    error_entry.pack(expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH )

    def log_error_callback():
        category = category_var.get()
        error = error_entry.get('1.0','end')
        if not error:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Please enter an error message')
            return
        log_error(category, error)
        messagebox.showinfo('Success', f'Error logged for {category} category')

    def delete():
        tk.Text.delete("1.0","end")

    log_button = tk.Button(root, text='Log Error', command=lambda:[log_error_callback(), delete()])
    log_button.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `delete()` function to refer to the `error_entry` `Text` widget specifically, rather than calling `delete` as a classmethod from `Text`

```
def delete():
    error_entry.delete("1.0","end")
```